# Trying to take EmployeeID & EName from dropdown to be used in a query to display table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a training matrix/Tracking website I am working on. I have the drop-down populated from the database from a different table. I was able to display table data from another two tables referencing the user id displaying the name of the user at the top and then a table with all training completed underneath.

I have got the dropdown working but I am struggling to get the database to pull data into a table using the id set in the dropdown box.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// We need to use sessions, so you should always start sessions using the below code.
session_start();
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}
?>

<?php
include ("templates/header.php");
include ("connect-db.php");
?>
<?php
$EmployeeID = $_POST['Get'];
    $sqlEmployee = "SELECT EmployeeID, EName FROM employee ORDER BY EName";
    $stmtEmployee = $dbCon->prepare($sqlEmployee);
    $arrEmployee = array();
    $stmtEmployee->bindValue(':EmployeeID', $EmployeeID); 
        if ($stmtEmployee->execute()) {
                $arrEmployee = $stmtEmployee->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

if (!isset($_POST['EmployeeID'])) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
    $stmtTable = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
    $stmtTable->execute();
}
?>
<center>
<form action="search.php" method="post">

<label for="EmployeeID">Employee</label>
    <select name="EmployeeID" id="EmployeeID">
    <?php
      for($i=0;$i<count($arrEmployee);$i++) {
         $row = $arrEmployee[$i];
      ?>
      <option value="<?= $row['EmployeeID'] ?>" <?php echo "Selected='selected'"?> ><?= $row['EName'] ?></option>
      <?php
      }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Get" value="Add New Record"></button>
</center>

<?php
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Home</th>
<th>Shift</th>
<th>Start Date</th>


</tr>";

while ($rowTable = $stmtTable->fetch($sql)) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $rowTable['EName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $rowTable['HomeBase'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $rowTable['Shift'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $rowTable['StartDate'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
$stmtTable=Null

?>

<?php
include ("templates/footer.php");
?>
```

I am getting an error where it doesn't get the variable. I know how to join databases but struggling to get a simple name shift startdate data.

New Code After Updates

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // We need to use sessions, so you should always start sessions using the below code.
    session_start();

    // If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit();
    }
    //includes for page
    include ("templates/header.php");
    include ("connect-db.php");
    // This one below is for the dropdown box to populate the user name

    $EmployeeID = $_POST['EmployeeID']; //changed this to EMployeeID from Get
    $sqlEmployee = "SELECT EmployeeID, EName FROM employee ORDER BY EName";
    $stmtEmployee = $dbCon->prepare($sqlEmployee);
    $stmtEmployee->bindValue(':EmployeeID', $EmployeeID);

    $arrEmployee = array();

    if ($stmtEmployee->execute()) {
        $arrEmployee = $stmtEmployee->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

?>
<center>
    <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <label for="EmployeeID">Employee</label>
        <select name="EmployeeID" id="EmployeeID">
<?php
        //this is a dropdown box for the top of the page to be able to select user to display data on

            for($i=0;$i<count($arrEmployee);$i++) {
                $row = $arrEmployee[$i];
                echo '<option value="' . $row['EmployeeID'] . '">' . $row['EName'] . '</option>';
            }

        ?>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="Get">Get</button>
    </form>
</center>

<table border='1'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Home</th>
            <th>Shift</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <?php
        //this is for the data in the table to be populated using the dropdown as the source for the id to display the user data ect.
    if (!isset($_POST['EmployeeID'])) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee Where EmployeeID = $EmployeeID";
        $stmtTable = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
        $stmtTable->execute();

        while ($rowTable = $stmtTable->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rowTable['EName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rowTable['HomeBase'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rowTable['Shift'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rowTable['StartDate'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    } else {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No records found</td>';
    }

    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php include ("templates/footer.php"); ?>
```

**Update 2**
By Changing the if (!isset($_POST['EmployeeID'])) to if (isset($_POST['EmployeeID'])) this made the page work but i still get the error "Notice: Undefined index: EmployeeID in C:\UniServerZ\www\search.php on line 19" when first loading the page but after clicking a name this goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first piece of advice that I have for you is to stay consistent in your coding methods and keep your code organized. For example, you define `$sql` but then don't use it for like another 20 lines. That is very disorganized. Everyone has to start somewhere so take my criticism to heart.

That being said, let's reorganize your code a little. From what I can tell, you're trying to display a table with the employees in it including their name, location (home base), shift, and start date. Provided that the database table contains that information, this should be fairly simple to accomplish.

One thing I did notice is `if (!isset($_POST['EmployeeID'])) {`. I am going to bet that's your problem. If `$_POST['EmployeeID']` is empty/not set, then `$sql` is empty. So let's do something like this instead:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    // We need to use sessions, so you should always start sessions using the below code.
    session_start();

    // If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit();
    }

    include ("templates/header.php");
    include ("connect-db.php");

    $EmployeeID = $_POST['Get'];
    $sqlEmployee = "SELECT EmployeeID, EName FROM employee ORDER BY EName";
    $stmtEmployee = $dbCon->prepare($sqlEmployee);
    $stmtEmployee->bindValue(':EmployeeID', $EmployeeID);

    $arrEmployee = array();

    if ($stmtEmployee->execute()) {
        $arrEmployee = $stmtEmployee->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

?>
<center>
    <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <label for="EmployeeID">Employee</label>
        <select name="EmployeeID" id="EmployeeID">
        <?php

            for($i=0;$i<count($arrEmployee);$i++) {
                $row = $arrEmployee[$i];
                echo '<option value="' . $row['EmployeeID'] . '">' . $row['EName'] . '</option>';
            }

        ?>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="Get">Ad New Record</button>
    </form>
</center>

<table border='1'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Home</th>
            <th>Shift</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php

    if (!isset($_POST['EmployeeID'])) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
        $stmtTable = $dbCon->prepare($sql);
        $stmtTable->execute();

        while ($rowTable = $stmtTable->fetch($sql)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rowTable['EName'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rowTable['HomeBase'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rowTable['Shift'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rowTable['StartDate'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    } else {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No records found</td>';
    }

    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php include ("templates/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: i have made the changes you have suggested but it is coming up with error "Notice: Undefined variable: EmployeeID in C:\UniServerZ\www\search.php on line 21"

Comment: It shows all records when first loading the page but then when clicking a persons name and submitting it displays no records and the error at line 21.

Comment: i have added the code now its updated to the bottom of the post, i have changed the Get to EmployeeID as the get didn't make since and threw the same error anyways. now if i add $EmployeeID = 19; then it will show results. but the number doesn't change when using the submit button. have i got the code mixed up somewhere.

Comment: Now working due to changes stated in "Update 2" but get a error message about Undefined index until i submit the form then it disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code as informed by Adam Miller (Thank You Adam) and then i changed the:

!isset to isset on the second query

and

```
$EmployeeID = $_POST['EmployeeID'] 
to
$EmployeeID = (isset($_POST['EmployeeID']) ? $_POST['EmployeeID'] : '');
```

which then relieves the need for the error as it checks if there is a input or not.

Thank you again Adam, You have been great.